# Date time is shown as invalid datetime in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

my code

```
 fromdate = DateTime.ParseExact(tt + "11:59:59 PM", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."

Comment: What is value of `tt`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got the same kind of error for that I used form collection, because of the missing space between your variable `tt` and `"11:59:59 PM"`.

```
fromdate = DateTime.ParseExact( tt + " 11:59:59 PM", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Where did `fc["fromedate"]` come from?

Comment: Where is that `fc["fromdate"].ToString()` from ? Cause Op never write anything relative to this in this question or a previous one..

Comment: @DragandDrop i got same kind of error for that i used form collection ,so i just posted my code ,and it worked for deepa

Comment: I will recommed [edit]ing it back to `tt` the orginal name in the question. And adding a little information about that space. because that was your fix. A one line with no explanation using a variable that no one know looked very suspicious.

Comment: @DragandDrop you can see in deepa code  ,there is no space in time string(tt + "11:59:59 PM", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)so i just posted need to add space or it might be like 06/18/201811:59:59 PM

Comment: and btw  thought of just saying the space missing and posted my code and thanks for the downvote @DragandDrop

Comment: I asked for clarification, and edited your answer. Don't shoot the messenger. I have done all of it trying to help you fix your answer.